# Apply check-box condition for only one row value else show warning in Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement, odoo, odoo-10

I have a One2many field. In this field i have check box field. And, I already applied a validation for check-box selection. And function work very well. Now, When i selected check then value is returning and if not selected then no problem. But, now I want that if any of the row check-box from One2many field is selected then value return else it show warning. Means, Single row check-box from overall One2many is sufficient for value returning.

**My code is here:**

```
@api.multi
def action_salepack_add(self):
    rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
    wiz = [q.id for q in self.wizard]
    res_wiz=  []
    #here is check box condition#
    for s in self.wizard:
        if s.check_box==True:
            res_wiz.append(s.id)
    #check-box condition over#
    if rec:
        line_values = {'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                       'wizards': [(6, 0, res_wiz)],
                       }
        sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add constrain, that return a warning;

```
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError


    @api.constrains('wizard')  # wizard is the one2many field
    def _check_grade_choisi(self):
        for record in self:
            l = []
            if not any([s.check_box for s in record.wizard]) : #Here i check if all checkbox field is False
                raise ValidationError("Your warning")
```

Comment: Thanks Anonymous...!!